# Get peer address within a thrift handler function

Tags: ruby, thrift

I am implementing a small thrift (0.6.0) server in ruby to play a role of proxy to another protocol with several connections (multiple clients) to a single server.  I want to be able and keep per-client data on the server side and track "session" parameters across multiple invocations of handler functions.

I currently use `Thrift::NonblockingServer` as `SimpleServer` does not seem to allow concurrent connections.

I know how to use `TCPSocket::peeraddr` but `Thrift::NonblockingServer::IOManager::Worker::run` creates a temporary `MemoryBufferTransport` with the frame it read and passes that as the input/output protocol down to the processor so it seems that the info is not passed down from there.

Is there a clean way to do this?
I was thinking of re-defining the above mentioned `Thrift::NonblockingServer::IOManager::Worker::run` to also include the fd, or other ID at an additional parameter to process or augment the proto instances but as I also have to worry about one layer of generated ruby code (`process_*` methods in `class Processor`) it seems a little heavy.

I wonder if someone did anything like this before.

Thanks!

p.s. this is similar problem to [this C++ thrift question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622682/thrift-different-handler-instance-for-each-socket)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I went about changing `Thrift::NonblockingServer::IOManager::Worker::run` to support this.

Few caveats:

- As I mentioned in the question I don't consider it clean (if nothing else I will have to monitor future thrift versions for changes in this function, this is based on 0.6.0).
- this is written to work with ruby 1.8 (or I would have gotten the non translated addr/port [see my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7636148/652904))
- I'm a ruby newbie .. I'm sure I've done some of this "wrong" (for example, should `$connections` be `@@connections` in `ConnEntry` or a diff class?).
- I am aware that the `Thread.current` hash for thread-local storage has [a namespace pollution issue](http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2008/04/10/lets-stop-polluting-the-threadcurrent-hash/)

First, at some central module:

```
module MyThriftExt

  $connections={}

  class ConnEntry
    attr_reader :addr_info, :attr

    def initialize(thrift_fd)
      @addr_info=thrift_fd.handle.peeraddr
      @attr={}
    end

    def self.PreHandle(fd)
      $connections[fd]=ConnEntry.new(fd) unless $connections[fd].is_a? ConnEntry
      # make the connection entry as short-term thread-local variable 
      # (cleared in postHandle)
      Thread.current[:connEntry]=$connections[fd]
    end

    def self.PostHandle()
      Thread.current[:connEntry]=nil
    end

    def to_s()
      "#{addr_info}"
    end   end end


module Thrift   class NonblockingServer
    class IOManager
      alias :old_remove_connection :remove_connection
      def remove_connection(fd)
        $connections.delete fd
        old_remove_connection(fd)
      end

      class Worker
        # The following is verbatim from thrift 0.6.0 except for the two lines 
        # marked with "Added"
        def run
          loop do
            cmd, *args = @queue.pop
            case cmd
            when :shutdown
              @logger.debug "#{self} is shutting down, goodbye"
              break
            when :frame
              fd, frame = args
              begin
                otrans = @transport_factory.get_transport(fd)
                oprot = @protocol_factory.get_protocol(otrans)
                membuf = MemoryBufferTransport.new(frame)
                itrans = @transport_factory.get_transport(membuf)
                iprot = @protocol_factory.get_protocol(itrans)
                MyThriftExt::ConnEntry.PreHandle(fd)    # <<== Added
                @processor.process(iprot, oprot)
                MyThriftExt::ConnEntry.PostHandle       # <<== Added
              rescue => e
                @logger.error "#{Thread.current.inspect} raised error: #{e.inspect}\n#{e.backtrace.join("\n")}"
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end   
  end
end
```

Then at any point in the handler you can access `Thread.current[:connEntry].addr_info` for connection specific data or store anything regarding the connection in the  `Thread.current[:connEntry].attr` hash.